# hot to write a test with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

This is my first time writing a test using RSpec with Capybara. Heres what I have so far:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'

describe "the signin process" do
before :each do
User.make(:email => 'test@test.com', :password => 'thisisatest')
end

  it 'signs me in' do
    visit 'sessions/new'
    within("session") do
    fill_in 'user email', :with => 'test@test.com'
    fill_in 'password', :with => 'thisisatest'
  end
  click_link 'login'
  expect(page).to have_content 'Thank You'
  end
end
```

Here is the message i got when I ran the test:

```
the signin process
signs me in (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

1) the signin process signs me in
 Failure/Error: User.make(:email => 'yedidyaweiner@gmail.com', :password => 'Shabbos!78')
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant User
 # ./spec/features/sign_in_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' 

Finished in 0.0006 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/sign_in_spec.rb:8 # the signin process signs me in
```

How can i fix this so the test passes? any suggestion on how to better write a test?

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "The signin process" do
  let!(:user) { User.create email: 'test@test.com', password: 'secret' }

  it 'signs me in' do
    visit 'sessions/new'
    within("session") do
      fill_in 'user email', with: user.email
      fill_in 'password',   with: user.password
    end
    click_link 'login'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Thank You'
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm, still giving me a failure.

Comment: Could you show `spec_helper.rb` file ? Does everything work in browser ?